# What are the requirements(pre_installations) of a windows portable devices application to run on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, wpd

Actually i have written a dll using WPD api to manipulate windows phone. Then i imported this dll in a java project using jna. All works fine on the system having complete c++ developement environment and Window development kit installed on it. But when this java application is made run on client system, which don't have c++ development environment(visual studio, WDK etc), it crashes at the time of wpd dll loading. 
My question is that, what are the pre installations necessory for wpd application to run on client systems. Off course we do not want to force the users to install visual studios and windows developement kit to use our application. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download visual c++ redistributable for the visual studio version you use, which I guess it's 2012

Download it here::   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Then install it on the computer you want to run the wpd app...you don't have to install visual studio on it...just the libraries..

Comment: thanks for replying, actually i didnt get you, we dont want to made installtion necessory for the user to use our wpd app.....

Comment: @Danieldonsn [Ahsan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3087188/ahsan) is using Visual Studio 2012. This answer would be more helpful if you could post a quote from the section you're referring to.

Comment: @daniel why not its working in my case, any suggessions? what can be the possibilities in your guess?

Comment: @daniel I checked my dll in dependency walker, it is showing 2 dll files missing , MSVCP110D.dll & MSVCR110D.dll. I tried to copy these dlls manually but no luck. This issue is ruining my whole day..

Comment: Last time I had a missing dll..I can't remember..
Try copying it...using command prompt...or upgrade your user account to administrator and see if works.....and the missing dll is on the computer you want to run it or on the computer you made it on..

Comment: @daniel I have created that dll in debug mode of visual studio not in release mode. Is it necessory to build the dll in release mode to fully achieve its functionallity? And i tried upgradation of user account to admin, and yes missing dlls are on client machine. I also tried to copy dlls manually, i coppied 30 dlls , but still those 2 missing dlls are not been recognized.

Comment: I was missing to import PortableDeviceGuids.lib in dll project. Importing this lib solved all my problems. Thanks daniel. Moreover you dont have to install visual c++ distributables compatible to your version of visual studio, i just installed visual c++ distributable 2005. It works like a charm.